# Angular app to CRM API - Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin 'localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, cors, dynamics-crm

I get below error when I make an angular request to crm endpoint of our api.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://acc-crm.domain.com:1234/api/data/v8.0/contacts' from origin
>   'http://localhost:49910' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Is there any configuration of crm api that I can change to allow my testing environment to access it or do I need to change something in the client side. I already tried adding `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` to the headers of the request.

Note: Eventually I will put the crm api calls on the backend C# app due to security issues.

Angular code for making the request:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Contact } from './contact';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactsService {

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('username:password')
    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getContacts():Observable<Contact[]> {
    return this.http.get<Contact[]>("http://acc-crm.domain.com:1234/api/data/v8.0/contacts", this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--disable-web-security` flag in chrome for your development. Just make sure to reenable it for any other websites you might visit.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/4374616

Comment: I added this flag to the Target of a new shortcut that I created, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs **when** u forget to assign the annotation `@CrossOrigin` **or** when the url you defined in your **angular's service does not matches with the mapping in the controller**

Comment: The url is correct as I checked in Postman. @CrossOrigin annotation looks like a Spring framework annotation but my backend service in this case is Microsoft CRM Dynamics.

Comment: @BigThinker yes your url might be fine in postman so your back-end is fine... the problem here is the **interchange** between *backend & frontend*. the url of your methods in angular's service must be  identical to those in your **api**